# Running postgres through java

Tags: java, database, postgresql

Before I get to the problem, here is what I am trying to do. So I have an assignment where you are supposed to take some sort of variable based code, interpret it, then spit out java code that connects to a database based on the latter. So basically it is java code that reads a file, and outputs a java file based on what is in the file. The output java code has to be output into a different directory (THIS IS THE PROBLEM). Also he gave us files that help us login and help with authentication. Here is the problem when I am in the directory with the output java code, and I run it, it connects to the database no problem, but when I am in any other directory, the code runs fine, but it doesn't want to connect to the database. Here are the arguments I use to run the code.

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc4-
9.1.jar:/home/undergrad/3/USERNAME/testDoc/bin/a1 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf a1
```

Since this is an assignment I can't put all my code on here, but here is the code to add something to a database. Keep in mind that this is generated code, and that that is why it looks so ugly, but the assignment is due tonight, so I can't really change that.

The stacktrace says that
the GSS authentication failed, it ended in a PSQLException. So there was an error while connecting. Yea it said it couldn't find the authentication files.

Comment: That's great, but this question gives us absolutely no information. The only thing resembling code you have posted is the arguments to run a random program.

Comment: Added code to the post

Comment: You also need to add the exception so we could understand what it is happening. Out of your explanation and without any error message, My guess is that you have some sort of problem with paths or directory permissions. You will have to change this code a bit so it can print out the stacktrace, after that post it here and we will look into it.

Comment: `-Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf` and 
`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf` need to be changed to specify the absolute path to your security files (or the relative path from the directory you're running in). Or you can copy the conf files to the directory where you're running your program.

Comment: I just made a hacky solution, I created a new bash file in java then cd'd in it, then I ran it with Runtime.